# How to draw a picture like this in python?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to move the point "0.0" to original point. But I failed: [image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
plt.plot(time - time[0], signal)  # Adjust the time array to start from 0
plt.title('Audio Signal')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I want to get a picture like this: [image]

Comment: how did it fail?

Comment: It's unclear where the difference between the two images is that is causing you a problem. Do you mean you want the axes limits at whole numbers, e.g. [0, 3.5] and [-8000, 10000]?

Comment: use `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify limits on you Y and X axis, working code should look something like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
plt.plot(time - time[0], signal)  # Adjust the time array to start from 0
plt.title('Audio Signal')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.xlim((time - time[0])[0], (time - time[0])[-1])
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

In this example I added `plt.xlim(...)`, xlim takes as argument a tuple of new limit for x axis.

The same goes for `plt.ylim()`. If you want the legend, you need to add label and `plt.legend()` to you plot:

```
...
plt.plot(time - time[0], signal, label = "OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav")
plt.legend()
...
```

The rest is a matter of adjusting plot color, figure size and dpi and font size.

Comment: `plt.margins(x=0)` would be a bit easier.